# What is the safe way to remove System Library Framework

Tags: macos

I'm new to OS X, and I need to get rid of one of the libraries under `/System/Library/Frameworks`.

I know I cannot just remove the directory, because there are symbolic links to its binaries from `/usr/bin`. How can I remove it?

The exact case: There is a Ruby.framework there which I want to get rid of because I want to manage Ruby versions using [RVM](https://rvm.io/).

Comment: You don't need to remove the system Ruby to install other Ruby versions using RVM! Just *override* it where necessary.

Comment: Don't remove anything you haven't installed yourself in `/System/`.

Comment: @Guillaume is right, but furthermore, don’t install anything yourself in `/System`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no safe way to remove files from `/System/Library/Frameworks` — anything you see there was installed as part of the operating system, and removing it will cause some applications to stop working correctly.

In particular, applications which make use of MacRuby / RubyCocoa will depend on the specific version of Ruby that is installed as part of this framework. [Don't touch it. Don't even *look* at it.](http://youtu.be/L6j6wg59Llw) You should be able to use RVM just fine with it where it is.

Comment: ok, thank you. I'll try to fix my problem differently. The exact problem is that I have different PATH on my terminal than in jenkins... but that's case for another question on stackoverflow I think